# Using $\mathfrak$ for digits in XeTeX

Tags: math-mode, xetex, logic, amssymb

I'm working on a XeTeX document and want to typeset digits or to be more precise, 1 and 0 as truth values in Fraktur via `\mathfrak`. I tried several tweaks and none helped. Would anyone know a workaround? Thank you in advance for your help!\

Edit: Sorry for my impreciseness. Here some additional information:
I tried to switch back to Computer New Modern in the document but it didn't work for the digits such as they would be in Fraktur. Here my command for CMR:

```
\newcommand{\lmr}{\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont}
```

Then I tried

```
\usepackage[math-style=TeX, bold-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[]{XITSMath-Regular.otf}
```

Letters in Fraktur seem to be no problem, but digits just won't work.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. What are your "several tweaks"? Can you edit your question putting a minimal working example, please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do you already have an OpenType Fraktur font ready at hand, to work with the Fraktur-type digits `0` and `1`?

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I just edited my question. Hope that's a bit more helpful. 
Regarding an OpenType font, I just tried the one's my question. Do you know one that would fit my needs better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using XeLaTeX, I will assume that you've already chosen a suitable Fraktur text font that includes numerals, not just letters. If that's not the case, I can suggest the [UnifrakturMaguntia](http://unifraktur.sourceforge.net/) fonts.

In the following example, `\true` and `\false` are defined as macros that access the (text mode) Fraktur numerals 1 and 0.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Numbers=OldStyle]
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\newfontfamily{\fraktur}{UnifrakturMaguntia21}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\newcommand\true{\text{\fraktur 1}}
\newcommand\false{\text{\fraktur 0}}

\begin{document}
0123456789 ABCDXYZ abcdxyz

{\fraktur 
0123456789 ABCDXYZ abcdxyz}

$\true$ $\false$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank your very much for your excellent help! You solution works like a charm for my project!

Comment: In PDFLaTeX, you could use the fonts from `oldgerm` or `blacklettert1`.

Comment: You can also `\setmathfont{UnifrakturMaguntia}[range=frak, Scale=MatchUppercase]` in `unicode-math` to make the same font your `\mathfrak` alphabet.

Comment: @Davislor - `range=frak` would be fine for uppercase and lowercase letters, but does it extend to numerals as well?

Comment: @Mico No, you would still need to use the other command for numerals. But it would give you matching `\mathfrak{F}`.  However, and alternative would be `\setmathfontface\unifrak{UnifrakturMaguntia}[Scale=MatchUppercase]` to use `$\unifrak{2}$`.

Comment: This is also a solution if you have issues when using a font, e.g., Fira Math, that has not mathfrak symbols.